# Animate objects in force layout in D3.js

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I need to create a data visualisation which would look like a bunch of floating bubbles with text inside of the bubble.

I have a partially working example which uses mock data prepared here:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomexx/qra2bkto/1/)

```
// helpers
var random = function(min, max) {
    if (max == null) {
        max = min;
        min = 0;
    }
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
};

// mock data
var colors = [
    {
        fill: 'rgba(242,216,28,0.3)',
        stroke: 'rgba(242,216,28,1)'
    },
    {
        fill: 'rgba(207,203,196,0.3)',
        stroke: 'rgba(207,203,196,1)'
    },
    {
        fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
        stroke: 'rgba(100,100,100,1)'
    }
];
var data = [];
for(var j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        var text = 'text' + i;
        var category = 'category' + j;
        var r = random(50, 100);
        data.push({
            text: text,
            category: category,
            r: r,
            r_change_1: r + random(-20, 20),
            r_change_2:  r + random(-20, 20),
            fill: colors[j].fill,
            stroke: colors[j].stroke
        });
    }
}
// mock debug
//console.table(data);

// collision detection
// derived from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1748247
function collide(alpha) {
    var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
    return function(d) {
        var r = d.r + 10,
            nx1 = d.x - r,
            nx2 = d.x + r,
            ny1 = d.y - r,
            ny2 = d.y + r;
        quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
                var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                    y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                    l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                    r = d.r * 2;
                if (l < r) {
                    l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
                    d.x -= x *= l;
                    d.y -= y *= l;
                    quad.point.x += x;
                    quad.point.y += y;
                }
            }
            return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
        });
    };
}

// initialize
var container = d3.select('.bubble-cloud');
var $container = $('.bubble-cloud');
var containerWidth = $container.width();
var containerHeight = $container.height();
var svgContainer = container
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', containerWidth)
    .attr('height', containerHeight);

// prepare layout
var force = d3.layout
    .force()
    .size([containerWidth, containerHeight])
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(0)
;

// load data
force.nodes(data)
    .start()
;

// create item groups
var node = svgContainer.selectAll('.node')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .call(force.drag);

// create circles
node.append('circle')
    .classed('circle', true)
    .attr('r', function (d) {
            return d.r;
        })
    .style('fill', function (d) {
            return d.fill;
        })
    .style('stroke', function (d) {
        return d.stroke;
    });

// create labels
node.append('text')
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.text
    })
    .classed('text', true)
    .style({
        'fill': '#ffffff',
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        'font-size': '12px',
        'font-weight': 'bold',
        'font-family': 'Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif'
    })
;

node.append('text')
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.category
    })
    .classed('category', true)
    .style({
        'fill': '#ffffff',
        'font-family': 'Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif',
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        'font-size': '9px'
    })
;

node.append('line')
    .classed('line', true)
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', 50)
    .attr('y2', 0)
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('stroke',  function (d) {
        return d.stroke;
    })
;

// put circle into movement
force.on('tick', function(){

    d3.selectAll('circle')
        .each(collide(.5))
        .attr('cx', function (d) {

            // boundaries
            if(d.x <= d.r) {
                d.x = d.r + 1;
            }
            if(d.x >= containerWidth - d.r) {
                d.x = containerWidth - d.r - 1;
            }
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {

            // boundaries
            if(d.y <= d.r) {
                d.y = d.r + 1;
            }
            if(d.y >= containerHeight - d.r) {
                d.y = containerHeight - d.r - 1;
            }
            return d.y;
        });

    d3.selectAll('line')
        .attr('x1', function (d) {
            return d.x - d.r + 10;
        })
        .attr('y1', function (d) {
            return d.y;
        })
        .attr('x2', function (d) {
            return d.x + d.r - 10;
        })
        .attr('y2', function (d) {
            return d.y;
        });

    d3.selectAll('.text')
        .attr('x', function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return d.y - 10;
        });

    d3.selectAll('.category')
        .attr('x', function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return d.y + 20;
        });
});

// animate
var interval = setInterval(function(){

    // moving of the circles
    // ...

}, 5 * 1000);
```

However I am now facing problem with animation. I cannot figure out **how can I animate nodes in force diagram**. I tried to adjust values of the data object and then invoke .tick() method inside setInterval method, however it didn't help. **I am utilizing D3 force layout.**

My questions are:

- How to make the bubbles "float" around the screen, i.e. how to
  animate them?
- How to animate changes of circle radius?

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: You don't have any links in the force layout.

Comment: Well, I don't need them for the sake of visualisation itself. The circles does not need to be connected this way.

Comment: The main and only thing why I am using force layout is the collision detection. Circles are nicely spread out across the canvas...

Comment: To keep them moving you could manage the force alpha value by having something like `force.alpha(0.1)` at the end of your tick function and you could also dynamically manage the friction to keep things moving.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/CoolBlue/vjccv9uv/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints! I updated my example, and I also added transition of when chaning circle size. Now it works almost as it should be, but the animations are too rapid. Any idea how to slow it down? Thank you! https://jsfiddle.net/tomexx/qra2bkto/2/

Comment: Yes, I have some ideas about that, see my answer below...

Comment: OK, I got it sorted.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think this one feels nicer...

---

### Key points

1. Charge set to 0, friction set to 0.9
2. Schedule parallel transitions on the radius and line in the timer callback
3. Use the dynamic radius for calculating collisions
4. Use a transform on the nodes (g element) to decouple text and line positioning from node position, adjust the transform x and y, only in the tick callback
5. Remove the CSS transitions and add d3 transitions so that you can synchronise everything
6. changed this `r = d.rt + 10` to this `r = d.rt + rmax` in the collision function to tighten up the control on overlaps
7. Closed loop speed regulator.  Even though friction  is set to 0.9 to dampen movement, the speed regulator will keep them moving
8. Use parallel transitions to coordinate geometry changes
9. Added a small amount of gravity

---

### working example

```js
// helpers
    var random = function(min, max) {
        if (max == null) {
            max = min;
            min = 0;
        }
        return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
        },
        metrics = d3.select('.bubble-cloud').append("div")
            .attr("id", "metrics")
            .style({"white-space": "pre", "font-size": "8px"}),
        elapsedTime = outputs.ElapsedTime("#metrics", {
            border: 0, margin: 0, "box-sizing": "border-box",
            padding: "0 0 0 6px", background: "black", "color": "orange"
        })
            .message(function(value) {
                var this_lap = this.lap().lastLap, aveLap = this.aveLap(this_lap)
                return 'alpha:' + d3.format(" >7,.3f")(value)
                    + '\tframe rate:' + d3.format(" >4,.1f")(1 / aveLap) + " fps"
            }),
        hist = d3.ui.FpsMeter("#metrics", {display: "inline-block"}, {
            height: 8, width: 100,
            values: function(d){return 1/d},
            domain: [0, 60]
        }),

    // mock data
        colors = [
        {
            fill: 'rgba(242,216,28,0.3)',
            stroke: 'rgba(242,216,28,1)'
        },
        {
            fill: 'rgba(207,203,196,0.3)',
            stroke: 'rgba(207,203,196,1)'
        },
        {
            fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
            stroke: 'rgba(100,100,100,1)'
        }
    ];

    // initialize
    var container = d3.select('.bubble-cloud');
    var $container = $('.bubble-cloud');
    var containerWidth = 600;
    var containerHeight = 180 - elapsedTime.selection.node().clientHeight;
    var svgContainer = container
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', containerWidth)
        .attr('height', containerHeight);

    var data = [],
        rmin = 15,
        rmax = 30;

    d3.range(0, 3).forEach(function(j){
        d3.range(0, 6).forEach(function(i){
            var r = random(rmin, rmax);
            data.push({
                text: 'text' + i,
                category: 'category' + j,
                x: random(rmax, containerWidth - rmax),
                y: random(rmax, containerHeight - rmax),
                r: r,
                fill: colors[j].fill,
                stroke: colors[j].stroke,
                get v() {
                    var d = this;
                    return {x: d.x - d.px || 0, y: d.y - d.py || 0}
                },
                set v(v) {
                    var d = this;
                    d.px = d.x - v.x;
                    d.py = d.y - v.y;
                },
                get s() {
                    var v = this.v;
                    return Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y)
                },
                set s(s1){
                    var s0 = this.s, v0 = this.v;
                    if(!v0 || s0 == 0) {
                        var theta = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
                        this.v = {x: Math.cos(theta) * s1, y: Math.sin(theta) * s1}
                    } else this.v = {x: v0.x * s1/s0, y: v0.y * s1/s0};
                },
                set sx(s) {
                    this.v = {x: s, y: this.v.y}
                },
                set sy(s) {
                    this.v = {y: s, x: this.v.x}
                },
            });
        })
    });

    // collision detection
    // derived from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1748247
    function collide(alpha) {
        var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
        return function(d) {
            var r = d.rt + rmax,
                nx1 = d.x - r,
                nx2 = d.x + r,
                ny1 = d.y - r,
                ny2 = d.y + r;
            quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
                    var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                        y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                        l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                        r = d.rt + quad.point.rt;
                    if (l < r) {
                        l = (l - r) / l * (1 + alpha);
                        d.x -= x *= l;
                        d.y -= y *= l;
                        quad.point.x += x;
                        quad.point.y += y;
                    }
                }
                return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
            });
        };
    }

    // prepare layout
    var force = d3.layout
            .force()
            .size([containerWidth, containerHeight])
        .gravity(0.001)
            .charge(0)
        .friction(.8)
        .on("start", function() {
            elapsedTime.start(100);
        });

    // load data
    force.nodes(data)
        .start();

    // create item groups
    var node = svgContainer.selectAll('.node')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .call(force.drag);

    // create circles
    var circles = node.append('circle')
        .classed('circle', true)
        .attr('r', function (d) {
            return d.r;
        })
        .style('fill', function (d) {
            return d.fill;
        })
        .style('stroke', function (d) {
            return d.stroke;
        })
        .each(function(d){
            // add dynamic r getter
            var n= d3.select(this);
            Object.defineProperty(d, "rt", {get: function(){
                return +n.attr("r")
            }})
        });

    // create labels
    node.append('text')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.text
        })
        .classed('text', true)
        .style({
            'fill': '#ffffff',
            'text-anchor': 'middle',
            'font-size': '6px',
            'font-weight': 'bold',
            'text-transform': 'uppercase',
            'font-family': 'Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif'
        })
        .attr('x', function (d) {
            return 0;
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return - rmax/5;
        });

    node.append('text')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.category
        })
        .classed('category', true)
        .style({
            'fill': '#ffffff',
            'font-family': 'Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif',
            'text-anchor': 'middle',
            'font-size': '4px'
        })
        .attr('x', function (d) {
            return 0;
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return rmax/4;
        });

    var lines = node.append('line')
        .classed('line', true)
        .attr({
            x1: function (d) {
                return - d.r + rmax/10;
            },
            y1: function (d) {
                return 0;
            },
            x2: function (d) {
                return d.r - rmax/10;
            },
            y2: function (d) {
                return 0;
            }
        })
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr('stroke',  function (d) {
            return d.stroke;
        })
        .each(function(d){
            // add dynamic x getter
            var n= d3.select(this);
            Object.defineProperty(d, "lxt", {get: function(){
                return {x1: +n.attr("x1"), x2: +n.attr("x2")}
            }})
        });

    // put circle into movement
    force.on('tick', function t(e){
        var s0 = 0.25, k = 0.3;

        a = e.alpha ? e.alpha : force.alpha();

        elapsedTime.mark(a);
        if(elapsedTime.aveLap.history.length)
            hist(elapsedTime.aveLap.history);

        for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            circles
                .each(collide(a))
                .each(function(d) {
                    var moreThan, v0;
                    // boundaries

                    //reflect off the edges of the container
                    // check for boundary collisions and reverse velocity if necessary
                    if((moreThan = d.x > (containerWidth - d.rt)) || d.x < d.rt) {
                        d.escaped |= 2;
                        // if the object is outside the boundaries
                        //   manage the sign of its x velocity component to ensure it is moving back into the bounds
                        if(~~d.v.x) d.sx = d.v.x * (moreThan && d.v.x > 0 || !moreThan && d.v.x < 0 ? -1 : 1);
                        //   if vx is too small, then steer it back in
                        else d.sx = (~~Math.abs(d.v.y) || Math.min(s0, 1)*2) * (moreThan ? -1 : 1);
                        // clear the boundary without affecting the velocity
                        v0 = d.v;
                        d.x = moreThan ? containerWidth - d.rt : d.rt;
                        d.v = v0;
                        // add a bit of hysteresis to quench limit cycles
                    } else if (d.x < (containerWidth - 2*d.rt) && d.x > 2*d.rt) d.escaped &= ~2;

                    if((moreThan = d.y > (containerHeight - d.rt)) || d.y < d.rt) {
                        d.escaped |= 4;
                        if(~~d.v.y) d.sy = d.v.y * (moreThan && d.v.y > 0 || !moreThan && d.v.y < 0 ? -1 : 1);
                        else d.sy = (~~Math.abs(d.v.x) || Math.min(s0, 1)*2) * (moreThan ? -1 : 1);
                        v0 = d.v;
                        d.y = moreThan ? containerHeight - d.rt : d.rt;
                        d.v = v0;
                    }  else  if (d.y < (containerHeight - 2*d.rt) && d.y > 2*d.rt) d.escaped &= ~4;
                });
        }


        // regulate the speed of the circles
        data.forEach(function reg(d){
            if(!d.escaped) d.s =  (s0 - d.s * k) / (1 - k);
        });

        node.attr("transform", function position(d){return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")"});

        force.alpha(0.05);
    });

    // animate
    window.setInterval(function(){
        var tinfl = 3000, tdefl = 1000, inflate = "elastic", deflate = "cubic-out";

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(Math.random()>0.8) data[i].r = random(rmin,rmax);
        }
        var changes = circles.filter(function(d){return d.r != d.rt});
        changes.filter(function(d){return d.r > d.rt})
            .transition("r").duration(tinfl).ease(inflate)
            .attr('r', function (d) {
                return d.r;
            });
        changes.filter(function(d){return d.r < d.rt})
            .transition("r").duration(tdefl).ease(deflate)
            .attr('r', function (d) {
                return d.r;
            });
        // this runs with an error of less than 1% of rmax
        changes = lines.filter(function(d){return d.r != d.rt});
        changes.filter(function(d){return d.r > d.rt})
            .transition("l").duration(tinfl).ease(inflate)
            .attr({
                x1: function lx1(d) {
                    return -d.r + rmax / 10;
                },
                x2: function lx2(d) {
                    return d.r - rmax / 10;
                }
            });
        changes.filter(function(d){return d.r < d.rt})
            .transition("l").duration(tdefl).ease(deflate)
        .attr({
            x1: function lx1(d) {
                return -d.r + rmax / 10;
            },
            x2: function lx2(d) {
                return d.r - rmax / 10;
            }
        });

    }, 2 * 500);
```

```css
body {
    background: black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.bubble-cloud {
    background: url("http://dummyimage.com/100x100/111/333?text=sample") 0 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/cool-Blue/d3-lib/master/elapsedTime/elapsed-time-2.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/cool-Blue/d3-lib/master/plot/plot-transform.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/cool-Blue/d3-lib/master/plot/fps-histogram.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/cool-Blue/d3-lib/master/plot/fps-histogram.css">
<div class="bubble-cloud"></div>
```

I like to use this formula for the spacing dynamic...

```
l = (l - r) / l * (1+ alpha);
```

and then use an alpha of about 0.05

No need for gravity or charge in my view, the only thing I change is to set friction to 1.  This means that velocity is maintained, but if your clients are getting motion sick then knock it back to 0.99.

> #### EDIT:
>
> changed to a slightly softer and more correct collision model
>       `l = (l - r) / l * (1/2 + alpha);`
>   Also added a little gravity to make it "cloud-like" and friction (see above)

---

### CSS transitions

I also tried to use CSS transitions but support seems patchy to say the least on SVG elements.

- Transition works on `circle` radius but not on `line` in chrome (45.0) and Opera
- In IE 11 and FF (40.0.3) none of the CSS transitions work for me

  I would be interested in any feed-back on browser compatibility as i couldn't find much on the internet about this.

I [experimented with velocity.js](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/5b3161f6be8bd2baac52) on the back of this and I think I prefer it for the transitions.

Comment: A very nice solution. Any idea how to slow down the whole animation?

Comment: Slower than my solution or slower than yours?

Comment: Updated mine according to yours: https://jsfiddle.net/tomexx/qra2bkto/3/ However the animation is too rapid. And even more when there is a collision while changing of the r.

Comment: Playing around with constructor helped.
var force = d3.layout
    .force()
    .size([containerWidth, containerHeight])
    .gravity(0.003)
    .charge(-70)
    .friction(0.8)
    .theta(0.2)
    .alpha(0.5)
;

Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think if you use the settings in my answer and add transitions on the radii then it will look OK.

Comment: Thank you for your help, do you think there is a way to slow down the animation without changing the constructor parameters like gravity, friction etc.? Thank you

Comment: You could... change the transition times? I don't know @tomexx, it's a very subjective question: what do you mean exactly? I tweaked the friction a little bit if that helps...

Comment: The thing is the friction has to be set to 1, otherwise the circles will get stuck after some time. But if the friction is set to 1, the movement of the circles is too rapid (after they collide on change of their radius). :/

Comment: How often do you have transitions happening? What effect are you going for exactly? Do you want them to feel like actual bubbles or do you want them to seem like they are in a lava lamp? If you slow down the transition time does that help? You need to express what you are going for dude.

Comment: @tomexx, I modified it a bit... maybe like that?

Comment: The transitions are happening every two seconds. If I should express it somehow, the bubbles should be more like lava lamp you mentioned, before they acted more like pool balls.

Comment: OK, that's pretty clear... how does it look now when you run the snippet?  You can adjust the speed of the nodes by changing `s0` in the `tick` callback. It's currently set at 0.2 which is about 10 pixels per second I guess... you can play around with that.  I also set the friction to 0.9 to calm it down during transitions. The speed regulator I added will keep them moving always though.